# Incomprehensible error with three print following

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary defined as follows:

```
SN = {}
SN[0] = {'verb' : 1 }
```

In my function I make 3 `print`s as follows:

```
print graph
print state
print graph[state]
```

(I do nothing else with these variables) and it returns:

```
SN  
0  
S
```

How is this possible? Why doesn't it return

```
SN
0
{'verb' : 1}
```

The whole code :

```
abstraction= {}
abstraction['de'] = ['déterminant']
abstraction['le'] = ['déterminant']
abstraction['un'] = ['déterminant']
abstraction['beau'] = ['adjectif', 'substantif']
abstraction['dodu'] = ['adjectif', 'substantif']
abstraction['grand'] = ['adjectif', 'substantif']
abstraction['méchant'] = ['adjectif', 'substantif']
abstraction['noirs'] = ['adjectif', 'substantif']
abstraction['petit'] = ['adjectif', 'substantif']
abstraction['desseins'] = ['substantif']
abstraction['loup'] = ['substantif']
abstraction['poulet'] = ['substantif']
abstraction['gosse'] = ["n'importe quoi"]
abstraction['mange'] = ['verbe']
abstraction['dort'] = ['verbe']


SN = {}
SN[0] = {'déterminant' : 1 }
SN[1] = {'adjectif' : 1, 'substantif' : 2 }
SN[2] = {'adjectif' : 3, '' : 'ok' }
SN[3] = {'' : 'ok' }

SV = {}
SV[0] = {'verbe' : 1}
SV[1] = {'transitions' : 'SN', '' : 'ok'}
SV[2] = {'' : 'ok'}


def transitions(data, graph, state = 0, transit = []) :
    print 'data avt if data :'
    print data
    if data : 
        if 'transitions' in graph[state] :
            return transitions(data, graph[state]['transitions'], 0, transit)
        symbol = data[0]
        if symbol not in abstraction.keys() : 
            return ['impossible, un des mots n\'est pas reconnu par l\'automate'] 
        for a in abstraction[symbol] : # loop on abstractions
            print graph
            print state
            print graph[state]
            if a in graph[state] :
                state = graph[state][a]
                return transitions(data[1:], graph, state, transit + [a])
        else :  
            return transit + [symbol] + ['impossible'] 
    else : 
        if '' in graph[state] :
            return transit + [graph[state]['']]
        else : return transit + ['impossible']
```

Comment: Is this your whole code? Where are `graph` and `state` defined?

Comment: It's obviously not my whole code. Graph and state are the arguments of my function : transitions(data, graph, state = 0, transit = [])(Thanks for your reply and sorry I didn't understant how to use the balises code)

Comment: Please post your whole code.

Comment: OK, but can you reply to my post because I have less than 10 positive evaluations so I can reply to my own question and my code is too big to post it in comment
Edit : sry i can edit my post..

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem here is that `graph == "SN"`, rather than (as you apparently expect) `graph == SN`.

To put it another way, `graph` is referencing a `str` object with value `"SN"`, **not** the `dict` object also referenced by the name `SN`.

Therefore `graph[0]` is the first character in the string `"SN"`, which is the letter `"S"`.

In the case `graph == SN`, the output from

```
print graph
print state
print graph[state]
```

would be:

```
{0: {'verb': 1}} # note: not 'SN'
0
{'verb': 1}
```

---

**Edit**:

Now that you've posted your code, this section:

```
SN = {}
SN[0] = {'déterminant' : 1 }
SN[1] = {'adjectif' : 1, 'substantif' : 2 }
SN[2] = {'adjectif' : 3, '' : 'ok' }
SN[3] = {'' : 'ok' }
```

creates a dictionary

```
SN = {0: {'déterminant': 1}, 1: {'adjectif': 1, 'substantif': 2},
      2: {'adjectif': 3, '': 'ok'}, 3: {'': 'ok'}}
```

However, in the next part:

```
SV[1] = {'transitions' : 'SN', '' : 'ok'}
```

you assign *the string `'SN'`* to the key `'transitions'`, not the actual dictionary `SN`. That should have been:

```
SV[1] = {'transitions': SN, '': 'ok'}
                      # ^ no quote marks
```

Also, as all of your keys are integers starting from zero, you could consider using a list instead of a dictionary, e.g.:

```
SN = []
SN.append({'déterminant': 1})
SN.append({'adjectif': 1, 'substantif': 2})
...
```

Comment: Looks like you're right. The OP wrote `SV[1] = {'transitions' : 'SN', '' : 'ok'}`, when he probably should have written `SV[1] = {'transitions' : SN, '' : 'ok'}`.

Comment: Ok thanks, it was that, i added an eval() and it works. Thank you ;)
But your way is probably better Kevin, I'm gonna take a look.
Thank for your answers.
BTW i don't understant why my topic has been locked...
Modos are very severe on this site!!

Comment: @user3581976 because you hadn't included the code that created `graph` or `state`, hence "lacks sufficient information".

Comment: Yes but you still could help me! You find the solution without the rest of the code... Anyway, it doesn't matter ;)
Have a good day